SFSafariApplication.dispatchMessage on XCode 16
We are making Safari extension for MacOS, that uses SFSafariApplication.dispatchMessage() to communicate between native and javascript parts of extension. Until recently everything worked, however after update to xcode 16 I started getting this error:
'dispatchMessage(withName:toExtensionWithIdentifier:userInfo:completionHandler:)' is unavailable in application extensions for macOS: Not available to extensions
'dispatchMessage(withName:toExtensionWithIdentifier:userInfo:completionHandler:)' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (SafariServices.SFSafariApplication)

I looked into documentation, however I did not find any hint of dispatchMessage() being replaced by something else. According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/messaging-between-the-app-and-javascript-in-a-safari-web-extension this is the way communication should be done.
Is it a bug? Or can someone direct me to working alternative of communication?

I'm seeing the same error, even putting the call to dispatchMessage() inside the SafariWebExtensionHandler class

It seems that dispatchMessage() is not meant to be used in this way. The native part of extension should only reply to messages from javacript part, but not initiate communication. Response shoud be done by NSExtensionContext acquired by beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) method of extension handler.
As I found out, it is not neccessary to respond to incoming message immediatelly. You can store NSExtensionContext, and use it for response later, when response is ready. Javascript part of extension will receive the response in callback set in browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage(). In this way I have solved my issue.
